# Where is llvm-config in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mingw, llvm

I am open to either a Visual Studio answer or a MinGW answer. I just finished building LLVM 3.2 using CMake and Visual Studio 2010. Everything went smoothly, but I have no `llvm-config`. Do I need it? Every example I see on the intertubes makes use of that tool. If I don't need it, how do I configure my project to make use of LLVM?

To be clear, I am not trying to use LLVM tools/compilers (like `clang` and whatnot). I am trying to write C++ code that uses the LLVM libraries to produce LLVM IR and even compile that stuff. I setup my include and lib folders. I ran `llvm-config` in Linux and saw a long list of macros and libraries.

I have a wonderful folder full of goodies. It just has no `llvm-config` in there: `C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\`

Answer (score 25):

`llvm-config` does not exist in windows prebuilt binaries. You need to compile from the source code to get it.

1. Grab [CMAKE > 3.5](https://cmake.org/download/) , install it and make sure you add it to PATH.
2. [Download Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
3. Donwload the [source code](http://releases.llvm.org/) (`9.0.1` is the latest as I'm writing this)
4. Extract the source code
5. `Cd` into the root of the llvm source-code
6. In cmd, type `cmake .` this will generate Visual Studio 2019 sln.
7. open sln file(`LLVM.sln`), change the build type to Rlease, build the whole project
8. navigate to your `Rlease\bin`, and there you have your `llvm-config.exe`

Comment: It would have saved me a day of figuring this out, but you have to run cmake in a "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019" window (in your Start menu), not in just regular PowerShell. Otherwise, include and link dirs for the Windows toolkit will not be found.

Comment: when installing VS, you have to tick "Desktop Development with C++" under "Workloads". It's the big visual panel with a lot of smaller rectangles and large icons. You will see some checkboxes on the right, some will be checked. No need to touch any of that, the default selection will suffice.

Comment: As of recently, you don't have to do this. LLVM has prebuilt executables now.

Comment: @flm Where can I find prebuilt executables?

Comment: @Koll in official releases on GitHub: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases
 . Search for `exe` downloads.

Comment: @flm from what I can see, the pre-build executables are missing llvm-config. The only thing returned by globbing *config* are `lib/clang/16/include/pconfigintrin.h`, `lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfigExtensions.cmake` and `lib/libear/config.h.in`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it was a pain. Instead of just running ``cmake .`` I had to create a build directory in llvm-project, and then run ``cmake -S llvm -B build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release``. Then I went into the build directory which was where LLVM.sln was.

Answer (score 6):

If you have built the LLVM in **debug** version all the executables (including llvm-config) have been placed in your build directory (containing Visual Studio project and solution files) in `bin/Debug/` subdirectory. In case of **release** build replace `Debug` with `Release`.

If you are interested in *using* LLVM on Windows more than building it, check out [Windows snapshot builds](http://llvm.org/builds/).

Comment: I've installed the latest windows snapshot build and `llvm-config` won't be available, do you know why?